# sorting mongo regex query in php

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I have a mongo collection and I'd like to obtain all the document whose names start with a given letter on PHP. My code:

```
$letter = "c";
$client = new MongoDB\Client();
$pme = $client->selectCollection("belgium", "pme");     
$regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex  ("^$letter", "i"); 
$query = array('name' =>  $regex); // 1
$query = array('name' =>  $regex, array( 'sort' => array( 'OrderBy' => 1 ) )); // 2
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query( array('name' => $regex), array( 'sort' => array( 'OrderBy' => 1 ) ) ); // 3
$cursor = $pme->find($query);
```

Whe I use query 1. I got all documents starting with letter c but not ordered. When I use query 2, I got nothing. And finally when I use query 3 I get almost every document, not just those starting with with 'c'. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mongo` method `sort` should be applied on `cursor` obtained by `find`:

```
$letter = "c";
$client = new MongoDB\Client();
$pme = $client->selectCollection("belgium", "pme");     
$regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex  ("^$letter", "i"); 
$query = array('name' =>  $regex);
// sort by field `name` happens here
$options = array("sort" => array("name" => 1), );
$cursor = $pme->find($query, $options);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the sort method of cursor no longer exist.

Comment: I've updated answer. Pls see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/214 for details.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was about to publish exactly this solution. I works now.